# Message box with if condition

Tags: excel, vba

I want to save as an excel file as `.csv` from `Sheet2` (Sheet name changes) so I want excel to pop up a message if I try to save as the file from `Sheet1`. I've a code to pop up the message but I'm not sure how to apply if condition for this scenario. Thank you for your help!!

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean)

    If SaveAsUI Then
        MsgBox "Make sure you are on correct sheet"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Should Work for you:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)

If SaveAsUI Then

    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then

        MsgBox "Make sure you are on correct sheet"
        SaveAsUI = False
    End If

End If

End Sub
```

If you are on Sheet1, the Msgbox will pop and sheet won't be saved.

Comment: One could also consider checking whether the sheet name is not equal to "sheet2" (or whatever the "correct" sheet name is) in case there are multiple sheets in the parent workbook. Concretely: 

`If ActiveSheet.Name <> "sheet2" Then`

Also, thanks of this; I didn't realize one could interact with the SaveAsUI directly like that.

Comment: Yeah ... But `Sheet2` should be specific name. Which doesn't seems like a case here. Also if you couldn't interact with `SaveAsUI`, then there is no point of this code as it will save the file nevertheless. We should be able to stop it from saving the file.

Comment: Great! Accept it as Answer if it worked :) @AmarKumarYadav